# Long running AsyncTasks for Fragments in a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity powered by a `FragmentPagerAdapter` which adds fragments as the user swipes left and right.

This child fragment that is added is currently static and contains a `ListView` of items. I intend to use and `AysncTask` to get items for the `ListView` but this process can take as much as 10-15 seconds.

I'm still lost with a few things:

From which method should my `AsyncTask` be invoked? Would it be the `onCreate` method of the `Fragment`? I'd only like the `AsyncTask` to be invoked when the Fragment is in focus.

The biggest question however is, what happens to my `AysncTask` when the user swipes away from the screen while the `AsyncTask` is loading. Is the Activity destroyed? Is there a way I can prevent the Activity from being destroyed? If I don't do this, all the progress made by the `AsyncTask` is lost and I have to reinvoke the `AsyncTask` when that `Fragment` comes into focus.

Thanks.

---

Reason for slowness:

I'm scraping a page with about a 150 records and jSoup is really, really slow. The problem with not using a service is that the data has a high probability of changing and I don't want to "pre-scrape" the data.

@Fildor suggested using a `Loader` to do the heavy lifting. A quick look at the `Loader` implementation showed that allows you persist data across short durations, like orientation change. I'm still wondering whether the `ViewPager`'s swing across `Fragments` would allow the data to persist in the `Loader` momentarily.

Comment: Have you heard about Loaders? http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html I think that is exactly what you want to use ...

Comment: Why does it take so long? Does it retrieve data from a network? In that case you might want to use a Service for keeping the data up-to-date and fill views from the local database.

Comment: @Fildor, I'm scraping a page with about a 150 records and jSoup is really, really slow. The problem with not using a service is that the data has a high probability of changing and I don't want to "pre-scrape" the data.

Comment: I see. Maybe you should edit your question and add these information. This is important for what to suggest to you.

Comment: @Fildor, I added some more information. +1 for the tip on the loader. I'm reading up on the `AsyncTaskLoader` as that would help me reduce the amount of code changes I have to do.

Comment: @Fildor, would you put your comment on using `Loader`s as an answer so I can accept it? I've created another question about using `Loader`s in an `Fragment` lifecycle. I'll go through the details there.

Comment: What if you need to update the UI?  Loaders do not have an equivalent of AsyncTask's onProgressUpdate.

Comment: Assuming that you've starting the loader from a `Activity` or `Fragment`, it needs to implement the `LoaderCallbacks`. This is a bunch of methods that the `Loader` calls when it has finished doing whatever. It takes a bit of toying to get your head around `Loaders` as they, when combined with a `Fragments` tend to have a tad complicated lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you heard about [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)?  I think that is exactly what you want to use ...

Comment: This should not be marked as the correct answer.  Loaders are not a good alternative if you need to update the UI, which AsyncTask's support.  There is no good way, that I know of, to run an asynchronous task that updates the UI, which will work with ViewPagers.

Comment: "Loaders

Introduced in Android 3.0, loaders make it easy to asynchronously load data in an activity or fragment." from: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html Read the comments , then you will see more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)
you can simply start asyncTask from onCreateView of fragment

Comment: Can you please give me a small sample?